# PHP creates dynamic links, how to call the right div on Jquery upon click to execute AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a very simple "Picture Gallery" for internal research at my lab.

I have an array with the file names (over 1000) from which I can call each one to be set into a table, displaying a 5 image row by five image column fashion.

The initial links are thumbnail size images, which should be the links to the low resolution version of the same image, which I have on a directory called lowres with the same file name.

I have created a hidden input field with the file name on them on a attempt to call the value of the input field and use this as the real value of the link.

how can I get the image links to work so I can call the low resolution image buy using an AJAX call?

Here is the PHP Code:

====================

```
    $array =     array("IMG_3944.jpg","IMG_3946.jpg","IMG_3947.jpg","IMG_3948.jpg","IMG_3951.jpg","IMG_3954.jpg","IMG_3955.jpg","IMG_3957.jpg","IMG_3958.jpg","IMG_3959.jpg","IMG_3960.jpg","IMG_3962.jpg","IMG_3963.jpg","IMG_3964.jpg","IMG_3965.jpg","IMG_3967.jpg","IMG_3971.jpg","IMG_3973.jpg","IMG_3980.jpg","IMG_3981.jpg","IMG_3983.jpg","IMG_3985.jpg","IMG_3990.jpg","IMG_3993.jpg","IMG_3996.jpg","IMG_4002.jpg","IMG_4005.jpg");
    $l = count($array);
    $z = $l/25;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mainContainer">
        <div id="menuPages">
         <?php
            /*=================   Page numbers    =====================*/
            echo '<table><tr>';
            for($w = 1; $w < $z; $w++){
                echo '<td><div class="page'.$w.'">'.$w.'</div></td><td>';
                if($w == 13){
                    echo '</tr><tr>';
                    continue;
                };
            };
            echo '</tr></table>';
         ?>
        </div>
        <div class="tableContainer">
            <?php 
                $x = 0;
                $y = 1;
                $cut = 4;
                $nxtpg = 24;
                echo "<div id='page".$y."'><table><tr>";
                for($x = 0; $x <= $l; $x++){
                    if($x <= $cut){
                        echo "<td><input type='hidden' id='hiddenInput' value='".$array[$x]."'><img id='image' name='".$array[$x]."' src='thumbs/".$array[$x]."' height='80px'></td>";
                        if($x == $cut){
                            echo "</tr><tr>";
                            $cut = $cut + 5;
                            continue;
                        };
                        if($cut == $nxtpg){
                           $y = $y+1;
                           echo "</table></div><div id='page".$y."'><table><tr>";
                           $nxtpg = $nxtpg +25;
                        };
                };
        };
```

====================
Jquery

Here I am attempting to "Alert me" with the result from the click.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#image").click(function(){
        var cCode = $("#hiddenInput").val(this);
        alert(cCode);
    });
    });
```

Comment: Format that code ffs...

Comment: The formatting is not strong with this one.

Comment: delegate your events because the element is not present at the onready event.

Comment: Use unique id's. instead, set class='image', and do $(".image").click(...

Comment: Use `$(document).on('click','#image',function(){...` instead of `$("#image").click(function(){...`

Comment: also, "this" is not a value, but an object, try to do alert($(this).attr("src"));

Comment: note - you are printing `id='hiddenInput'` & `id='image'` in a loop -> `for($x = 0; $x <= $l; $x++){` so you will end up with `n` number (in this case `$l`) of `id='hiddenInput'`/`id='image'`. Since `id`s are to be unique, you will only be able to select the 1st of each with `$("#image").click(function(){ var cCode = $("#hiddenInput").val(this);`. `. You probably want to change those to classes -> `class='hiddenInput'`/`class='image'`

Comment: @littleLouito `this.src` is much faster and much better practice than `$(this).attr("src")`

Answer (score 0):

Updating your code. You should never apply same id to html elements. Alos to grab the lowres image you need not fire a ajax request. Since you already getting the name in your JS function, you can create a div container to show the image.

```
   ...............
    <div class="tableContainer">
        <?php 
            $x = 0;
            $y = 1;
            $cut = 4;
            $nxtpg = 24;
            echo "<div id='page".$y."'><table><tr>";
            for($x = 0; $x <= $l; $x++){
                if($x <= $cut){
                    echo "<td><img class='image' name='".$array[$x]."' src='thumbs/".$array[$x]."' height='80px'></td>";
                   ......
```

Javascript code should be like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".image").click(function(){
        alert(this.attr('name')); //as image name
    });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very very much to everyone who contributed to my question,I have to apologize for the unformatted message since it was my very first time asking something on this forum. I am currently evaluating all options although I managed to get a result that does what I want, but I may find a cleaner way to do it... I will include my results as I have them.  Thanks again